# Is there a way that I can limit the text to 2 / 3 lines using SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, xcode11, ios13

I am trying using

```
var body: some View {
    Text("This is large text. Is there a way that I can unwrap the large text as discussed").lineLimit(2)
}
```

FYI:
**I knew**

```
var body: some View {
    Text("This is large text. Is there a way that I can unwrap the large text as discussed").lineLimit(nil)
}
```

It will wrap the text to say n number of lines.

Answer (score 3):

Call `.lineLimit(3)` on the `Text` element. (Technically, it can be called on *any* `View`, in which case it will limit the lines of *all* `Text` elements in that view.)

From `SwiftUI.View`:

```
    /// Sets the maximum number of lines that text can occupy in this view.
    ///
    /// The line limit applies to all `Text` instances within this view. For
    /// example, an `HStack` with multiple pieces of text longer than three
    /// lines caps each piece of text to three lines rather than capping the
    /// total number of lines across the `HStack`.
    ///
    /// - Parameter number: The line limit. If `nil`, no line limit applies.
    /// - Returns: A view that limits the number of lines that `Text` instances
    ///   display.
    public func lineLimit(_ number: Int?) -> Self.Modified<_EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Int?>>
```

Answer (score 0):

because `.linelimit` is not working as expected for the time being you can simply wrap the Text element inside a VStack if you have multible text like title and subtitme give that VStack multilineTextAlignment modifier and center that text with the parameter `.center` or you can add `.multilineTextAlignment(.center)` modifier directly to the Text element :

```
 VStack{
        Text("This is large text. Is there a way that I can unwrap the large text as discussed")
        .font(.title3)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
                             
        }.padding()
         .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
```